# Python Tkinter entry widget won´t accept input

Tags: python, tkinter, window, tkinter-entry

I have run into a very weird Problem with Tkinter entry widgets.
When I try to enter something into them they don´t accept my input.

After some PC restarting and Python reinstalling I figured out why this happens: I had a messagebox just before the `root.mainloop()` in the code. The code looks something like this:

```
def xyz():
    if not messagebox.askyesno("Title","Some text"):
        exit()
xyz()
root.mainloop()
```

I found, to resolve the issue you can just manually focus on a different window and then back again. 
I would like to know if there is some better way to do this? I would like to keep my messagebox, AND dont´t want the unelegant solution of manually changing window focus.

Comment: Python does not do any magic, so does not know which window you want switched, so you have to code things yourself (whether is it unelegant or not), i.e. focus_set() whatever you want focused.

Comment: I think this is a known bug. I'm guessing you're on Windows, because I think that's the only platform that has this bug. What if you do `root.after_idle(xyz)` instead of calling `xyz()` directly? That gives `mainloop` a chance to start up, but still shows the messagebox as soon as the GUI starts up.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks, your solution worked perfectly! I didn´t know about `after_idle()` before.

Comment: @CurlyJoe Thanks for you reply! What I didn´t mention in my post is that the `root` window is in focus automatically, yet the entry widget doesn´t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the code like this:

```
def xyz():
    if not messagebox.askyesno("Title","Some text"):
        exit()
root.after(10,xyz) #show the messagebox after root.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```